# Extracting part of a multi-line string using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the below line from a multi-line string:

```
eth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ee/64
```

When I try to extract just `eth6.36   Link encap`, I get an error.

```
test = 'ifconfig eth6.36\r\neth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ee/64 Scope:Link\r\n          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1\r\n          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0\r\n          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0\r\n          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 \r\n          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:7004 (6.8 KiB)\r\n\r\n'

match = re.match('(eth6.36\sLink encap:)', test)
print match.groups()
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Which error? can you share it?

Comment: @Giordano: `match` will be `None` since the regexp doesn't match anything. Then, the next line will cause an `AttributeError` since `None` doesn't have a `groups` attribute. I took the liberty of adding that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches from the beginning of the string. Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead as it matches anywhere in the string:

```
>>> match = re.search('(eth6.36\s+Link encap:)', test)
>>> print match.groups()
('eth6.36   Link encap:',)
```

Also, you have to specify that multiple whitespace characters match: `\s+` (note the +).

Answer (score 1):

You want this, There was a mistake in the formation of regex

```
import re
test = 'ifconfig eth6.36\r\neth6.36   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A0:36:9F:5F:24:EE  \r\n          inet addr:36.36.36.10  Bcast:36.36.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0\r\n          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe5f:24ee/64 Scope:Link\r\n          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1\r\n          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0\r\n          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0\r\n          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 \r\n          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:7004 (6.8 KiB)\r\n\r\n'

match = re.search('(eth6\.36\s*Link encap:)', test)
print match.groups()
```

Output

```
('eth6.36   Link encap:',)
```

Comment: I noticed you excape the dot in your search regex, where others above do not.  Are they missing something? is the dot considered meta in this string if not escaped?

Comment: They aren't missing anything. The `.` replaces one character. In their case it's getting matched with the `.` itself (It could match with anything else). In my case it is getting replaced with `.` exactly

Answer (score 0):

Use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with [`multiline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) instead. You also need a quantifier for `\s`.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(eth6.36\s+Link encap:)',test, re.M)
['eth6.36   Link encap:']
```

If you're sure that only one result will come use `search` and remove the *grouping parentheses*:

```
>>> re.search(r'eth6.36\s+Link encap:',test).group()
'eth6.36   Link encap:'
```